# Can a bijective function be formed between all the even numbers and the number one with all the odd ones?

Tags: functions

We know that a bijective function can be formed between odd and even numbers, and also both are bijective with natural numbers. My question is, can a bijective function be formed between all the even numbers and the number one with all the odd ones?

Comment: What does "... and the number one with all the odd ones" mean?

Comment: A bijection can be found between *any* two infinite sets of integers.

Comment: (even numbers and the number one) and (all the odd ones).

Comment: Take a bijection $f$ between the even integers and the odd integers. Now define $g$ on the set of all even integers and odd integers as follows: $g(1) = f(2)$; $g(2)=f(4)$, $g(4)=f(6),\ldots$; and $g(2k)=f(2k)$ for all $k\leq 0$.

Comment: Look up "Hilbert's Hotel". There is no problem adding any finite number of elements to the domain of such a bijection; you can even add a countable number of countable collections to the domain, and still be able to define a bijection.

Comment: @MenuPrincipal: The reason for that misreading is that the idiom is  “between this and that”, not “between this with that”.